# Error in geolocation api and google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, visual-studio-2012

I don't know what is wrong with my code i've build it in brackets and it worked but when i've move in visual studio its telling me that he can't read the latitude property more precise with Google Developer tools i'm getting this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined"

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                getLocation();
            });
            function getLocation(){
                if(navigator.geolocation){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
                }else{
                    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
            }

            function initialize(position){
                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatLng ,
                    zoom: 18,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                map.set('styles', [
                    {
                        featureType: 'road',
                        elementType: 'geometry',
                        stylers:[
                            {color: '#C4C4C4'},
                            {weight: 0.6}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        featureType: 'road',
                        elementType: 'labels',

                        stylers:[,
                            {saturation: -100},
                            {invert_lightness: false}
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        featureType: 'landscape',
                        elementType: 'geometry',
                        stylers: [
                            { visibility: 'on' },
                            { hue: '#ffffff' },
                            { gamma: 1.4 },
                            { saturation: 82 },
                            { lightness: 80 }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        featureType: 'poi',
                        elementType: 'geometry',
                        stylers: [
                            { visibility: 'off' }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        featureType: 'poi.school',
                        elementType: 'geometry',
                        stylers: [
                            { visibility: 'off' },
                            { hue: '#fff700' },
                            { lightness: -15 },
                            { saturation: 99 }
                          ]
                    }
                ]);

                var iconBase = 'Images/';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    icon: iconBase + 'romb.png',
                    map:map
                });
            }


            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

UPDATED!

After looking again on my code i've discover a problem in brackets i didn't use at the top of the html document the DOCTYPE tag but in vs2013 i've used it, after i removed the tag in vs2013 worked also i've removed the google call line. but now i have another question: Why with the DOCTYPE tag didn't work?

Thank you for your help,
Aurelian!

Comment: Looks like the problem is with position.coords.latitude.  You need to give it actual lat and lng values so it can center the map on those coordinates, so you have to set those properties before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Which calls the initialize function with no arguments, and doesn't have a latitude property.

```
function initialize(position){
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're passing the position variable back to your initialize function.  So when it tries to get the latitude and longitude properties it can't because position is undefined.

Try changing this

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
```

to this

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  initialize(position);
});
```

Comment: and another person also pointed out, you're initializing the map twice, and not passing position either time.  You do it once with jquery at the top through geolocation function and again using the gmaps sample code at the bottom.

Comment: btw, if you are doing that as a fallback method, you don't need to re-initialize the map.  You can initialize it once with your fallback latitude and longitude, then try your geolocation, and if it works you can use setCenter to move the map over their actual location.